# How to add a class to scald images?

Tags: 7, theming, scald

I am using the Drupal 7 [**Bootstrap**](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme and [**Scald**](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald). I have figured out how to use contexts but would like it so that when an image is shown it has the `img-responsive` class.

Can this be done by manipulating the render array?

Can anyone point the best way to achieve this?

Comment: can you give specific examples of where/how the images are being shown?  I don't think there's one method that would work across all instances.

Comment: I am using the image in a view.  
I have rewritten the field so that it outputs the standard atom markup:
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://127.0.0.1/sites/default/files/styles/600_width/public/thumbnails/image/download.jpg?itok=N5129iDg" width="600" height="300" alt="download.jpg" title="download.jpg"> 

It's in there that I want to add the class.

Comment: The OP asked on #drupal-scald (Freenode) and was answered. Could you post back your own solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to implement a quick fix by wrapping the atom in a div then targeting via CSS.  However your advice on creating a custom player seems like it would be the better approach.  Something I will be looking into once the site goes to testing and I have a bit more time.

Comment: If you're outputting the img tag yourself in a view, just add the class to the markup! `<img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="127.0.0.1/sites/default/files/styles/600_width/public/…; width="600" height="300" alt="download.jpg" title="download.jpg">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting an extra `<div class="img-responsive">` wrapper around the standard atom markup generated by Scald works (sort of - the legend doesn't look good).

However, I've solved this by just copying the Bootstrap `img-responsive` class, using it as an override for the Scald `dnd-atom-wrapper` class:

```
// Just copy the Bootstrap CSS for img-reponsive.
.dnd-atom-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

This seems to work for all image atoms in Scald (it may break other types of atoms - I only use Scald atoms for images).

I really want to emulate the complete Bootstrap "thumbnail" concept (including nice borders and captions), but using  standard Scald atom css classes, so I ended up with these overrides for the relevant classes (this is the default player - must be slightly adapted to work with the HTML5 player):

```
// CSS fror Scald image atoms
.dnd-atom-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
  transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.dnd-legend-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 100%;
}
.dnd-atom-wrapper,
.dnd-drop-wrapper img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
  display: block;
}
.dnd-atom-wrapper.atom-align-right {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    margin-left: 0.7em;
  }
}
.dnd-atom-wrapper.atom-align-left {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    margin-right: 0.7em;
  }
}
.atom-align-right {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
.atom-align-left {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

I have this CSS in `less/overrides.less` in my Bootstrap subtheme.

Remember to compile it with *lessc* and clear caches for it to work.

Below you can see it in action.  Big screen on the left, small screen on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked this out.  It is still a hack, but it doesn't add a wrapper, and don't require additional CSS. I don't think it *can* be solved "the Drupal way", given the way **Scald** works.

It turns out that markup for **Scald** atoms is already present in the render array and a class added as an attribute to the render array (as you would normally do) will be ignored.

Adding the following to the top of `node.tpl.php` works:

```
$markup = $content['field_scald_atom_ref'][0]['#markup'];
$markup = str_replace('typeof="foaf:Image"',
  'typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive"', $markup);
$content['field_scald_atom_ref'][0]['#markup'] = $markup;
```

What this code snipped does is to hack the markup already generated by **Scald** to include `class="img-responsive"`.